# SIM not detected ! Raspberry Pi connected via a 4g huawei e3370 USB modem using a SIM card

Tags: raspbian, networking, modem

[Updated]
I have a 4g huawei  e3370 with a rpi 3. I am trying to configure my modeme e3370 but I am getting an error: SIM not inserted. Do you have any idea?

Here is my /etc/wvdial.conf :

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB6
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
Init3 = ATX3
Stupid Mode = on
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = *99#
New PPPD = yes
ISDN = 0
Username = internet
Password = internet
Baud = 9600
```

When I run `sudo wvdial` I get the folowing including the error:

```
    --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
OK
--> Sending: ATX3
ATX3
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
    +CME ERROR: SIM not inserted
    --> Invalid dial command.
    --> Disconnecting at Wed Jun  9 15:15:06 2021
```

I am using card sim bouygues from france.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: `ERROR: SIM not inserted` how is that something to do with a PIN?

Comment: I was thinking maybe because of the pin the modem is not able to read the sim